# Installing QJson on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qjson

Now I'm porting my project from Linux to Windows.

I've built QJson using QtCreator by [instructions](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/get_it/windows.html), and now I have one simple question: where I should move the library dll-file, and what I should specify in `LIBS +=` line in the `.pro` file?

Here's content of that line in Linux:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lqjson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add  `LIBS += YourPathTodllFile/Yourdll.dll`  in your profile.